# Ubuntu 12.04 won't boot

Tags: 12.04, boot-failure, initramfs

I upgraded to 12.04 a while ago and the internet dropped out halfway through so something went wrong, I would have upgraded/downgraded it but I can't boot off a CD/USB and terminal and my update centre had no internet connection. I booted it up thismorning and it got stuck on the Ubuntu with little dots under it page for ages before finally presenting me with a blank screen reading:

```
Busybox (Ubuntu v1.18.5-1ubuntu4) built in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.
(initramfs)
```

I googled the problem and tried the suggested `mount -t ntfs-3g/dev/sda /root -o force` and it came back with the message:

```
mount: can't read 'etc/fstab': No such file or directory.
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you were trying to do with that command but you made a typeo.  There should be a space after the ntfs-3g part.

Answer (score 0):

Use a live USB and boot your system.

Make sure you can mount your main partition in which your Ubuntu is installed. Lets assume it is /dev/sda1

Unmount that partition (NECESSARY). Now run this command which will fix errors in partition:

```
sudo fsck -a /dev/sda1
```

Make sure you you can mount the partition. Restart your system. it should work now.